# Problema em setar token de atutenticação

Tags: javascript, react, jwt, graphql

Estou com problema na autenticação da minha aplicação, faço o processo de inserção de um `token` `jwt` ao login do usuário, porém não consigo fazer a aplicação ler o `token` ou estou perdendo-o em algum momento, deixarei o [link do repo no github](https://github.com/pedroffd/react-graphql-auth) e indicarei onde está a função de autenticação(que uso como middleware)

A função de autenticar está em `api/src/graphql/middleware/auth.js`

pra quem quiser rodar a aplicação, estou usando banco `postgre`, e será necessário criar um arquivo `.env` com a configuração:

```
PG_USERNAME=postgres
PG_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD
PG_DATABASE=postgres
PG_PORT=5432
PG_HOST=localhost
API_SECRET=YOUR_API_SECRET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar o token do localStorage no environment do relay

````
  return fetch("http://localhost:5000/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      ++"Authorization": "Bearer" + localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables
    })
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}```
````